# COUNTIFS ignoring rows based on values in row

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have been struggling with these two problems for the better part of the day. Please see this link to an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1odU7oqc-WviLzQcghkbYbQG-4DC70-Q_hszb22Chljw/edit?usp=sharing
This is a simplified document I use to see which lecturer (name) has has added which of the 5 documents (on the right) to an online learning environment (one row for each course). The courses can be given in semester 1, 2, or in both. I want to use this document to automatically highlight a name if any of the five boxes on the right is empty if the semester I want to check (Cell D1) is similar to Column E.  Furthermore, only the first time a name appears in red, should the e-mail appear so as well.
For this, I of course use conditional formatting (please see those formulas, also pasted in column M (range column C and D) and N (Range column D). N is the white conditional formatting overruling M, in which a N="TRUE" means it is whitened out).

Example 1 (Ans) shows how I intend the programme to work. The first instance shows shows both the name and e-mail in red, later instances do too unless the semester is not similar or all boxes on the right are ticked.
Example 2 (Bertrand) shows the first problem. If the first instance of a red name and e-mail occurs in a semester 'both', the second time the name should be red the e-mail does so as well. This keep occurring until a semester is similar to Cell D1, after which it is normal again.
Example 3 (Carel) shows the second problem. If the first instance in which a certain lecturer occurs all boxes on the right are ticked, the second time he occurs but does not tick all boxes his name shows in red but his e-mail doesn't.

I think problem 1 (example 2) is solved if I can get 'both' to somehow mean both 1 and 2, but I don't know how.
I think problem 2 (example 3) is solved if I can get COUNTIFS to ignore the rows is which all five boxes are ticked.

However, I have no clue how to do this. Is anyone able to help me with either (but ideally both) problems?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think I've understood what you need.

**For the first part** (where a lecturer has less than all 5 subjects containing 'x' AND where E is either the value of cell D1 or the value of 'both'), try this:

Delete both of your existing conditional formatting rules.

Create a new conditional formatting rule for range = `C4:C21` (or perhaps further down your sheet to row 977), with a custom formula of:

`=AND(COUNTIF($G4:$K4,"x")<5,or($E4=$D$1,$E4="both"))`

The style for the rule should have a red background.

**For the second part** (updated), this is a bit tricker with conditional formatting but I can offer a solution determined by the value of cells, like you had.

Delete the contents of cells `M4:N21` (21 being where you have a formula in the furthest cell).

In cell `M4`, add the following formula:

`=arrayformula(if(iferror(if(ifs(E4:E=$D$1,1,E4:E="both",1)+if(G4:G&H4:H&I4:I&J4:J&K4:K <>"xxxxx",1,)=2,D4:D,),)<>"",countifs(iferror(if(ifs(E4:E=$D$1,1,E4:E="both",1)+if(G4:G&H4:H&I4:I&J4:J&K4:K <>"xxxxx",1,)=2,D4:D,),),iferror(if(ifs(E4:E=$D$1,1,E4:E="both",1)+if(G4:G&H4:H&I4:I&J4:J&K4:K <>"xxxxx",1,)=2,D4:D,),),row($E4:$E),"<="&row($E4:$E))=1,))`

It might seem a little complex, but it's done this way to use the functions that are compatible with `ARRAYFORMULA` so that it will keep working down the sheet as far as you have values in rows.

Now create a new conditional formatting rule for range = `D4:D21` (or perhaps further down your sheet to row 977), with a custom formula of:

`=$M4=true`

The style for the rule should have a red background.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, problem 1 is solved. However, I might have been unclear for problem 2. I have added a fourth example (Daan), showing my problem: despite all boxes being checked, the first name still pops up in red, which should not happen since I wouldn't need that e-mail address. Furthermore (although this is not necessarily a problem but would ideally be included), the first 'carel@hotmail.com' turns red instead of the second, in which the actual problem (not all boxes are checked) occured.
Do you happen to know of a solution?

Comment: OK, I think I know what you mean. Only where cells in Col 1 are red, do you just want the first instance of the corresponding email to be red?

Comment: I've updated the solution. It only uses one `AARAYFORMULA` in M4. The formula in N4 needs to be dragged down. I'll see if I can improve this for you.

Comment: Amended solution to part 2 for `arrayformula`. Might not be the most elegant, but it works! :-)